# How to delete grid lines from Chart in WindowsForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

How can I remove grid lines from a chart? I am using the standard Chart library.

Comment: What have you tried? What's failing? Is there an error? Where is your code?

Comment: I read the documentation but I haven't found anything about grid. No property and no method;/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming a single ChartArea, you can try these settings:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
```

Otherwise you may want to use:

```
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
```

where, "ChartArea1" is the Series Property-->Chart-->Chart Area "ChartArea1"

Comment: Yes! Thx a lot. And what about interval of X? I want it to be 1 2 3 etc, but now I have data in series and on x i have 0,77 1,77 2,77 3,77. I set IsStartedFromZero = true;Interval = 1;Maximum = 4;Maximum = 4; in chartarea properties.

Comment: @user1068894 Sounds like a different question to post.  StackOverflow likes to work with single questions.

Answer (score 41):

You can disable `MajorGrid` or `MinorGrid` of each of the axis of the desired chart-area:

```
mainChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
mainChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
mainChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
mainChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
```

as seen below:
https://github.com/sinairv/MSChartWrapper/blob/master/MSChartWrapper/ChartWrapper.cs#L58-L61

Comment: This should be accepted, IMO. Cleaner than just hiding them by adjusting the width.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just using the designer, you can navigate your way to the MajorGrid property like this...

[image: VS Chart MajorGrid Property]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to property to set different styles as well

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.NotSet;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.NotSet;
```