# Remove Grid Lines From Chart Control C#

Tags: c#, charts, linechart

I have an application with `Chart control` that dynamic updated with data via timer:

```
Series series;
MyObject obj...

series = new Series();
chart1.Series.Add(series);
//chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend("DifferentLegend"));
//chart1.Legends["DifferentLegend"].DockedToChartArea = "Default";
//chart1.Series["Series1"].Legend = "DifferentLegend";
//chart1.Series["Series1"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;

series.Color = Color.Blue;
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.BorderWidth = 3;
chart1.Series.Add(series);
//chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
//chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 4;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
```

Timer tick:

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    series.Points.Add(obj.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);
}
```

I want to change it style and remove the squares from the control:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Remove the grid lines?

Comment: How ? what should i remove ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871287/how-to-delete-grid-lines-from-chart-in-windowsform

Comment: See my update, still not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
```

To disable `X-Axis` Labels from the Chart :

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: you are calling `chart1.Series.Add(series);` two times in ur code remove first one and move the second one to last.

Comment: BTW how can i remove the number from the X Axis ?

Answer (score 0):

This then?

```
mainChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
mainChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
mainChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
mainChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
```