# Remove axis line from chart c#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I want to remove axis line from chart in c#. I want to have only point there. How to do that?

**Here is a result**

[image]
<sub>(source: [akusherstvo.ru](https://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image804874.png))</sub>

**Here is Code:**

```
public ChartBuilder(ref Chart chart, double minValue, double maxValue)
{
    this.chart = chart;
    this.chart.Series.Clear();

    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minValue;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxValue;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = minValue;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = maxValue;

    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;

    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;

    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;

    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineColor = Color.Transparent;

}
```

Comment: have you tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871287/how-to-delete-grid-lines-from-chart-in-windowsform

Comment: @gypsyCoder its already done, I want more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason neither setting the `LineWidth` works nor making the `LineColor = Color.Transparent`, which usually works fine for `Chart` elements.

But you can set it to have the same `Color` as the `Chart`'s `BackColor`:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineColor = chart1.BackColor;
```

[image]

To remove a few more things you can write this:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
```

And :

```
chart1.Legends.Clear();
```

**However** the simplest way is to **disable** the `axes`:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False; 
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
```

No need to do **anything** else to the axes, now..

Now there is only the dot to be seen. I don't post a screenshot of that one point..  ;-)

Comment: thanks, It's working, but small lines is stell here [link](http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image804874.png)