# How can I hide vertical line

Tags: c#, mschart

[image: line]

**I want to remove the lines I showed in the picture** Because it is a very absurd views *(not only marked two)*

[image: result]

I am trying this code but it does not do anything

```
chart1.ChartAreas.First().AxisX.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Black);
chart1.ChartAreas.First().AxisX.LineWidth = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas.First().AxisX.InterlacedColor = Color.White;
```

*I am changing Interval like this , it working but above code does not work*

```
chart1.ChartAreas.First().AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Comment: Why are those two grid lines 'absurd' ?? They look just as innocent as the others..!

Comment: See [How to delete grid lines from Chart in WindowsForm?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8871287/719186)

Comment: I think it frequently seems worse when, and labels do not seems smooth

Comment: @LarsTech thanks , i searched remove and hide its named delete,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The answer from* [How to delete grid lines from Chart in WindowsForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8871287/719186)

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
```